# handling Multiple implementation of interface

Tags: spring, interface

Say I need to rely on several implementations of a Spring bean. I have one AccountService interface and many implementations: DefaultAccountServiceImpl,SpecializedAccountServiceImpl and etc(actual count is 40).

How is this possible (injecting one or the other implementation) in Spring boot?

Which implementation will the following injection use?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/inject-bean-by-name.html, if there are multiple implementations, a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException will be thrown. This can be fixed with @Qualifier annotation, where the name of the desired bean should be given.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Qualifier` [annotation of Spring boot](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier), when autowiring it.

Example:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultAccountServiceImpl")
AccountService defaultAccountServer;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("specializedAccountServiceImpl")
AccountService specializedAccountServiceImpl;
```

Comment: if i add as you have mentioned, i need to autowire 40 qualifier beans?

Comment: Hi Husam, Thanks. i got a instance of a class from the below code.                                 Class<? extends <Interface-name>> sanitizer = EntityServiceImplMap.getInstance().getSortSanitizer(entityId,
    subEntityId);                                                        Now i have userimpl.class value in sanitizer. but when i am accessing the userimpl class methods, i couldnot access it through my sanitizer obj. how can i achieve?

Comment: If you need each of your implementation so you have to implement all of them. But you may use `Abstract class`. I didn't get your above comment sorry.

Comment: Thanks, EntityServiceImplMap.getInstance().getSortSanitizer(entityId, subEntityId) is giving the return value as "RolesServiceImpl.class". After getting this value i cannot call the methods from my RolesServiceImpl class through the reference "sanitizer". when i am trying to call sanitizer.newInstance(), I am getting null error for other autowired properties

Comment: No problem, check if you may have missed annotating your classes with `@Component` so that they could be managed by Spring